# fill datatable column with database values as images

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datatable, asmx

I want to retrieve list of users names from database and display it in datatable as images and when hover on any image, it displayed the user name. My code display developer name column as a list of developers separated by comma.
[image]

Here is my code:

### Project class

```
public class Projects
    {
        public int project_number { get; set; }
        public string project_name { get; set; } 
        public string developer_name { get; set; }
        public  Image team_members { get; set; }
    }
```

### json

```
columns: [
     { 'data': 'project_name' },
     { 'data': 'developer_name' },
     {
        "data": "team_members",
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
        var markup = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
           markup += '<img src="images/img.jpg" class="avatar" title="'++'">' }
       return markup;
       }
   }             
]
```

### asmx:

```
    public void GetProjects()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection statement");
            conn.Open();

            var projects = new List<Projects>();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("getProjects", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var Project = new Projects
                        {
                            project_number = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1].ToString()),
                            project_name = dr[2].ToString(),
                        };
                        projects.Add(Project);

                        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT user_name FROM Users WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM User_Projects WHERE project_number = @project_number)", conn))
                        {
                            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_number", Project.project_number);
                            List<string> developerNames = new List<string>();

            using (SqlDataReader rdrDev = com.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (rdrDev.HasRows)
                                {
                                    while (rdrDev.Read())
                                    {
developerNames.Add((string)rdrDev["user_name"]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                   Project.developer_name = string.Join(", ", developerNames);
                        }
                    }
                }
                var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(projects));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Since there are multiple developers/team_members on each project, shouldn't you have like a one to many relationship? So I imagine you'd be best to create a TeamMembers class and a mapping table between teammembers and images?

Comment: @Dennis1679 I did this idea before. I have developers class and projects class but because I have nested sql statement, I delete the developers class and add developer name to Projects class. See my edit to have a look on the query.

Comment: Well the problem with the list is, I think, the fact you declare `public  Image team_members { get; set; }` in your class, and then you are saying in the code that `Project.team_members` should be set to `Handcards` but Handcards you made this a list. Hence the error. If that makes any sense to you.

Comment: `developer_name` contains all names of developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameter `render` in column declaration.
Split developers name and process it to correct generate markup:

```
{
   "data": "developer_name",
   "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
       var markup = '';
       var developers = data.split(',');
       for (var i = 0; i < developers.length; i++) {
           markup +='<img src="images/img.jpg" class="avatar" title="' + developers[i] + '">'
       });
       return markup ;
   }
}
```

Comment: could you please give me some educational link about render function? thanks a lot again you made my day very happy

Comment: @alaa ok. Give me a few minutes

Comment: @alaa there [official docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) that I've used to understand how it work