# How to loop inside datatable columns declaration?

Tags: javascript, image, datatable

I have the below datatable declaration and want to display images depend on some column value (team_members). How can I declare the for loop inside columns declaration? i want this result:
[image]

```
var datatableVariable = $('#projects-progress').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [
    { 'data': 'project_name' },
    { 'data': 'team_members_value' }, // to be hidden
    {
     //I want loop here depend on the number of team_members_value (second column above)
     mRender: function (o) { return '<img src="images/img.jpg" class="avatar" alt="Avatar">';
    },
/* EDIT Delete */
    {
    mRender: function (o) { return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>'; }
    },
  ]
 });

<table id="projects-progress" class="table table-striped projects">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Project Name</th>
                          <th>Team Members</th>
                          <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Where you want to display image?

Comment: @Pavlo Zhukov in the datatable (x column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter `render` in column declaration.

```
{
   "data": "team_members_value",
   "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
       var markup = '';
       for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
           markup +='<img src="images/img.jpg" class="avatar" alt="Avatar">'
       });
       return markup ;
   }
}
```

You need to do something like this:

1. Add render callback.
2. Proceed your `team_members_value` data to render needed markup, save it and return.

Comment: it just show me the team_member_value not the img! where to put the img tag?

Comment: `//render there to show your img` put render code here. `markup += '<img src ="' + team_member + '">';`

Comment: this not work fine! I want to display the same img 3 times id team_memver_value =3; I try : markup +='<img src="images/img.jpg" class="avatar" alt="Avatar">' but, it display one image only

Comment: take a look on the screen shot in my post

Comment: Do you know how to display developer_name (one of database values) as a title of the image? I retrieved developer_name in code behind and count the number of them in team_members_value

Comment: @alaa yes. If you have it in `data: data` you can get in render function by `full['developer_name']`

Comment: To explain the full issue, could you please take a look on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346915/fill-datatable-column-with-database-values-as-images    Many thanks